# Date Format in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date-format, days

I'm using below code to display date

```
  Dim fromdt as date=05/28/2014     
  Dim todt as date=05/30/2014      
  Dim Dates as string
 Dates = fromdt.ToString("dd MMM yyyy").ToString + "-".ToString + todt .ToString("dd MMM yyyy").ToString
```

The output comes with the above format but i want like this(Tue 28 May, 2014 - Fri 30 May 2014)

Can any one give me the syntax for this??

Comment: You don't need to call `.ToString` on everything!

Comment: It's working but i want this type of format-- Tue 28 May, 2014 - Fri 30 May 2014

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code is working fine. but your date needed to be in double quotes.

```
    Dim fromdt As Date = "5/28/2014"
    Dim todt As Date = "5/30/2014"
    Dim Dates As String
    Dates = fromdt.ToString("dd MMM, yyyy")+ "-"+ todt.ToString("dd MMM, yyyy")
    Console.Write(Dates)
```

Or the result will be like this

```
28 May, 2014-30 May, 2014
```

for day with date you can use

```
Dates = fromdt.ToString("ddd MMM d, yyyy")+ "-" + todt.ToString("ddd MMM d, yyyy")
```

the result will be

```
Wed May 28, 2014-Fri May 30,2014
```

if you do not want comma in date you can remove it.

Comment: i'm not saying your answer is wrong, the method is not right, you are using .ToString, even when its not required, So I asked you to read the comments on Question asked by OP

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
Format(fromdt, "ddd d MMM, yyyy") + "-" + Format(todt, "ddd d MMM, yyyy")
```

Comment: ohh!!!...sorry ...my mistake...edited it..
@MarkHall..thanks for pointing the mistake :)

Comment: Can you give me syntax for this type of format?eg:- Tue 28 May, 2014

Comment: when u execute the above format, the result will be like this
 - "Wed 28 May, 2014-Fri 30 May, 2014". 

this is what you asked for right?

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim d1 As Date = #5/28/2014#
Dim d2 As Date = #5/30/2014#

Dim Dates As String = String.Format("{0:ddd d MMM, yyyy} - {1:ddd d MMM, yyyy}", d1, d2)
'Result - Wed 28 May, 2014 - Fri 30 May, 2014

Dim DatesWithParens As String = String.Format("({0:ddd d MMM, yyyy} - {1:ddd d MMM, yyyy})", d1, d2)
'Result -(Wed 28 May, 2014 - Fri 30 May, 2014)
```

Hth...

Answer (score 0):

Nothing much wrong with your code except the .ToString that you are using after giving the format.

Just change the code to this and it will work fine :

```
Dates = fromdt.ToString("ddd d MMM yyyy") + "-" + todt.ToString("ddd d MMM yyyy")
```

here :

> **ddd** - Day of week 
>  **d** - Date in number 
>  **MMM** - Month
>   Abbreviation 
>  **yyyy** - year in number